# Tiff annotations

Tags: .net, image, image-processing, tiff

1. Where can i find Tiff annotations (Wang/Kodak) format specs? Need to parse some of them and put to text file. Wasted many hours googling with no result.
2. What SDKs for .NET can operate with that tags? Free sdk's are preferred. Libtiff has limit of 32K to any tiff tag but some of annotation tags such as bitmap can be longer.
   Thanks!

Comment: TIFFs flexibility was its greatest strength and also its downfall. I doubt that any library ever created can deal with every possible variation of TIFF file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spec is public, but the content holder (eistream) took down their website a few years ago. It is currently being preserved on the web archive here:

http://web.archive.org/web/20030124024322/http://www5.eistream.com/support_pro/faqs/annospec.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've saved my days :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm not sure about .NET support, but there used to be SDK support for annotations in the old Office 2003 Imaging for Windows.