# TIFF annotation coordinates

Tags: annotations, coordinates, tiff

I need help trying to find a utility or method to search for annotations (filled rectangles) in tiff files and determine their coordinates.  I'm not a programmer, but I'm profficient with vbscript and powershell....any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not very familiar with the TIFF specification as you can probably tell....i've downloaded the specs from adobe, but can't make heads or tails of what i need.

i have looked at the following related post:
[Tiff annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805197/tiff-annotations)

it suggested looking at:
http://web.archive.org/web/20030124024322/http://www5.eistream.com/support_pro/faqs/annospec.htm
which says that annotations are referenced in tag 32932....however, i've used libtiff.org's tiffinfo.exe to view the tags associated with a test file (that has an annotation).....it does not show tag 32932.

so that's where I'm at.  again thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have an annotated TIFF file, you can check which tags it contains. Then you can specifically search the web for values associated with your annotations. (Is your test file publicly available, or can you make it so?)

Comment: @Jongware i don't have a means to make the file available publicly.  here is the tiffinfo:
TIFF Directory at offset 0x8536c (545644)
  Subfile Type: (0 = 0x0)
  Image Width: 2543 Image Length: 3215
  Resolution: 299.999, 299.999 pixels/inch
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: LZW
  Photometric Interpretation: RGB color
  Extra Samples: 1<unassoc-alpha>
  Orientation: row 0 top, col 0 lhs
  Samples/Pixel: 4
  Rows/Strip: 1
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Software: Pixel Translations Inc., PIXTIFF Version 58.4.218.725
  Predictor: horizontal differencing 2 (0x2)

Comment: I don't see any tags related to annotations. Please use a tool that shows the actual tags (and edit relevant information into your post, don't dump it in a comment).

Comment: do you have any suggestions on a tool to show "actual tags"?

Comment: No. I'd *write* one from scratch, using the (freely available) TIFF specs, sooner than attempting to find something that might or might not do what I need. I've done so in the past for similar questions.